# Did not! - Did too!

Tags: idioms, slang, construction

I often hear the **"Did not! - Did too!"** in TV series and films.

I know perfectly well what it means but why is it the word *"too"*?

> As best as we know "too" stands instead of "indeed/so" and implies an
>   affirmative statement! It's much shorter to use in spoken English!
>
> I believe it is an idiom of some kind but I couldn't find it!

Example:

> *Brother:* Mom, Linda kissed a boy at school today!
>   *Sister:* Did not!
>   *Brother:* Did too!

Comment: Can you provide a little more context in which you've heard this phrase?

Comment: @CinCout That's been a long time ago! But you can google, I think you'll find many sources!

Comment: I believe something similar was asked recently, but I can't recall which question.  I *too* would like to know if there is a reason for this idiom.

Comment: -1 for "But you can google, I think you'll find many sources!” Really? Supplying good examples is the responsibility of the person asking the question, not those who are trying to help. Please carefully read [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: @J.R. Really? Then there's a million questions here that aren't supposed to be here. Since most of them can be answered by googling for examples. You can certainly find answers on other resources. I'm not confident in the way you proper us to ask something. Maybe I've heard that in a movie ten years ago, can't I ask? What if I've seen a sign somewhere and don't remember where, shouldn't I ask then?

Comment: @J.R. I agree that some context and some explanation should be since English is all about context but does it really matter where I get the examples or the context? If someone is trying to learn a new preposition, he can make up examples that you/we can explain.

Comment: Sovereign - You should at least tell us what you can. If it was from a movie  10 years ago, but you can’t remember, just say so. But I think it’s in poor taste to tell the people answering your question: _"But you can google, I think you'll find many sources!”_ And yes, there are many questions on ELL that could do a better job of providing context. Once you reach 1K rep, though, you ought to be asking better questions, and setting a good example.

Comment: @J.R. I was never meant to be rude or whatever. It's just that it's common in Russia, if something can obviously be found online, there's no need to copy-paste examples. I remember I first saw this construction a long time ago in a cartoon, but can't remember the title. I'm trying my friend but I can't see how my questions aren't good enough.

Comment: I’m not trying to be rude, either. I’m just trying to help you understand how you can turn a mediocre question into a good one: by taking the time to provide an example or two, making sure people understand exactly what you’re asking and not just guessing and hoping they are right. A reminder from our [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): **_"Remember to make an effort to research your question before posting it, and be sure to add as much detail as you can when explaining your problem.”_**

Comment: @J.R. I wish to say that.. most of the research I make doesn't answer my questions completely. No grammar book explains everything word for word!

Comment: Sov - Precisely. The way the Stack Exchange is suppose to work is this: You share what research you performed, telling us what you found, and then you ask your question in a way that the community can help you figure out the rest.

Comment: It's two kids **talking**. One says "I didn't do it". The other says "Did too".  Which is used for : Yes, you did. And the first one says: Did not, to repeat I did not do it. If you don't understand the kid angles here, you have not understood it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Did too" is an American slang for "Yes, you did".

Since it is shorter (hence quicker to say), people tend to use it in arguments (as in the example you gave).

[Source](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/did-not-did-too.1676099/)

**EDIT:**

Regarding OP's question

> "Why exactly the word 'too'?"

The phrase "Did too" is a slang (informal language commonly used in speech than writing). It doesn't make sense to debate why a specific word was chosen/used over the other.

Comment: But why is it exactly the word *"too"*? Why not *"Did do"*?

Comment: Thanks, but I can find such sources myself.

Comment: @SovereignSun - "too" just means something like "indeed", as you point out.   "Did do" sounds very strange, perhaps because the fuller version is "You did too kiss him", so I can't see how "do" would work as a replacement in there.

Comment: @stangdon 'too' in most cases means 'also', 'as well'. So it sounds as if she kissed the boy also. While 'do' emphasizes the action. You did do kiss him, don't lie.

Comment: @SovereignSun - Except that "You did do kiss him" is wildly incorrect.  You could say "You did do *that*" or "You did *kiss him*", but you can't string together three verbs in a row.  It looks like you are looking for a dictionary definition for "too" in "You did too."  The best thing I can point to is ["4. (used as an affirmative to contradict a negative statement): I am too!"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/too)  It's idiomatic.  That's just the way it is.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zP7pgInSybI

Comment: @CinCout I am not so sure that it does not make sense to ask why a specific word was chosen. I do not think that language evolves randomly and so there has to be a reason. It can be difficult to find it, but it still makes sense to wonder.

Comment: This is not slang. It's how kids talk. See my comment under the question.