# Is it correct to use only "no is not" in this case?

Tags: pronouns, slang

Is it correct to reply with just "no is not" as an answer to some statement, without "it".

For example:

— It is easy. 
— No, is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English speakers never say "is not" by itself without a subject.
For example, here is a sample argument:
"Your homework is not done!"
"it is"
"no **it's**not"
"yes it is"
"no, it's not"

Comment: Or **it isn't**.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.  [A well-formed English sentence has (at least) a subject and a verb.](https://guides.lib.uoguelph.ca/Grammar/SentenceStructure#:%7E:text=A%20sentence%20is%20a%20group,is%20sometimes%20represented%20as%20SVO.)  "is not" has no subject.

That said, [you sometimes hear people, mostly children, use this structure as a kind of shorthand](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111949/did-not-did-too):

> "Jamie broke the computer!"
> "Did not!"
> "Did too!"